# New order email custom

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, order-email

I have designed my **email** and have added the following code to get the **order information** but two problems

It doesn't show product image?
How do I edit the style? It doesn't appear right

```
{{if order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}
{{var order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}</p></div>
```

[image: the email]

Answer (score 0):

The template on the default theme is:

```
frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items.phtml
```

There are a loop in wich load each item:

```
frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml
```

You can move that file to your theme and modify it to show the images and modify the html.

Comment: Then do I need to change the order.getEmailCustomerNote to something else?

Comment: No, thats ok, you can change the template directly.